# How to make string format float with fixed precision and locale type decimal separator?

Tags: python

I want to write values from dictionary to file with fixed decimal lenght and with use locale specified decimal separator.

I can do either one of those, but can I compine them both "....".format(x) call.

```
try:
   log_file = open(file_path, "a")
   for x in record.values():
       log_file.write(str("{:.2f}".format(x)) + ";")
```

Comment: What happened when you did what you did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [locale](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.str) module:

`locale.str`
Formats a floating point number using the same format as the built-in function str(float), but takes the decimal point into account.

```
import locale
locale.str(round(1.111, 2))
```

Comment: Working for me! Thanks! Just need to remember to set locale in script. I used : locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the '.' used by the format method to any separator you want by the `replace` function. E.g. if you want to use a `+` as a separator, you use the following statement:

```
"{:.2f}".format(5.2).replace('.', '+')
```

Comment: Works also, but Ilocale feels like more generic solution.